# Dúvidas busca binária

Tags: algoritmo, desempenho

Partindo do principio que a **busca binária** funciona apenas com **vetor de inteiros ordenados**, caso eu tenha que buscar um inteiro em um vetor ordenado a velocidade da busca seria muito mais rápido do que uma busca sequencial, mas minha duvida é, se meu vetor não estiver ordenado quanto influenciaria na velocidade em relação a busca sequencial caso eu tenha que ordená-lo? e se pudermos ir mais a fundo pense em uma busca binária em um vetor de String o processo seria:

1. Converter cada item do vetor em um numero decimal
2. Ordenar o vetor
3. Realizar a busca binária

Nesses dois exemplos quanto influenciaria na velocidade em relação a busca sequencial os processos antes da busca binaria?

Comment: Depende da quantidade de buscas que irá realizar após a ordenação. Se forem poucas pesquisas não vale a pena.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> se meu vetor não estiver ordenado quanto influenciaria na velocidade em relação a busca sequencial caso eu tenha que ordená-lo?

Se você tiver que ordenar um vetor para depois fazer uma busca com certeza o processo será mais lento, só compensará ordenar se você tiver que fazer várias buscas.

> uma busca binaria em um vetor de String

A classe `String` (em Java) implementa a interface `Comparable` o que permite que se use o método `binarySearch()` diretamente sobre seu vetor de Strings, sem a necessidade de transformar em inteiros (seja lá como você planeja fazer isso).

Ou seja, você pode ordenar o vetor simplesmente fazendo assim:

```
String[] sa = {"um", "dois", "tres", "quatro"};
Arrays.sort(sa);
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(sa, "um")); //imprime "3" que é a posição do
                                                   //elemento "um" no vetor ordenado
```

> quanto influenciaria na velocidade em relação a busca sequencial os processos antes da busca binaria?

Depende do tamanho do seu vetor e de quantas vezes você fará uma busca nele depois de ordenado.

Apenas saiba que o método `sort()` tem complexidade `O(n log(n))`.

Referências:

[método Arrays.sort() - Java SE7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29)

[Classe String - Java SE7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

[Interface Comparable - Java SE7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado @Math sua resposta foi bastante construtiva , como faço uma busca binária em um vetor de strings sem precisar converte-los para inteiro como faz a classe String do Java?

Comment: Não entendi bem sua pergunta. O código que eu pus na resposta faz exatamente isso, com o Arrays.sort() e Arrays.binarySearch(). Se não for isso, poderia esclarecer qual sua dúvida?

Comment: Minha dúvida é sobre o funcionamento interno do método binarySearch, na sua resposta você disse que ele faz a Busca binária sem precisar converter para inteiros,  como ele faz isso?

Comment: Toda classe que deseja ser ordenada deve implementar a interface [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) e sobrescrever o metodo `compareTo()`. A classe String faz `this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)` para dizer qual String está antes de outra quando ordenadas, esse código quer dizer que a comparação de duas Strings é o resultado da comparação baseado no valor Unicode de caracter a caracter de cada uma delas. Veja o [compareTo() da String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 3):

Bom, a velocidade com que os processos necessários para tornar a busca binária viável são realizados está diretamente associada ao **número de vezes** que os mesmos são executados.

No caso, se o vetor não estiver ordenado e você não souber uma "pista" sobre um jeito de ordená-lo de uma maneira mais rápida e eficaz (baseando-se nos próprios valores do vetor), uma busca sequencial será sempre a melhor alternativa.

Em suma, só é interessante fazer uma busca binária ao invés da sequencial quando:

1. O vetor em questão é ordenado (como já apontado em sua pergunta);
2. O número de tarefas realizadas para ordenar um vetor a partir de um algoritmo **já conhecido** é **menor** do que o número de comparações de valor por valor.

---

Pense na seguinte situação (usarei C# para demonstrar):

- Você deseja buscar por um número (38 por exemplo) dentro de um vetor com 40 posições que não está ordenado:

  ```
  int valorDesejado = 38;
  int[] vetor = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
                    22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 39};
  ```

  Você tem uma pista ou, nesse caso, sabe explicitamente que seu vetor tem os dois últimos valores invertidos.
- Comparando os dois tipos de buscas (considerando gasto de processamento em operações de soma, divisão, disjunção e comparação de maneira equivalente), **na sequencial** você realizaria 38 testes de comparação (tirando a comparação do próprio laço) e faria o incremento de sua variável contadora `i` o mesmo número de vezes:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < vetor.Length; i++)
      if (valorDesejado == vetor[i])
          Console.WriteLine("Valor encontrado na posicao " + i);

  /* Total:
   * 38 Operações
   * 38 Comparações
   */
  ```

  Por outro lado, antes de realizar a **busca binária**, você só precisa de três operações para trocar os valores de posição (para isso usarei o [algoritmo XOR de troca](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_XOR_Swap)), somando ao total duas operações e uma comparação por ciclo:

  ```
  // Usando XOR Swap: 3 operações
  vetor[38] ^= vetor[39];
  vetor[39] ^= vetor[38];
  vetor[38] ^= vetor[39];

  // Busca binária
  int esq, meio, dir;
  esq = -1;
  dir = vetor.Length;

  while (esq < dir - 1) // Para buscar pelo 38, o ciclo só se repetirá 6 vezes
  {
      meio = (esq + dir) / 2; // Duas operações (soma e divisão)
      if (vetor[meio] < valorDesejado) // Uma comparação
          esq = meio;
      else
          dir = meio;
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Valor encontrado" + dir);

  /* Total:
   * 6 * 2 + 3 = 15 Operações
   * 6 * 1 = 6 Comparações
   */
  ```

Answer (score 3):

As eficiências seriam:

- **n.log(n)** para ordenar
- **log(n)** para buscar quando ordenado binarysearch
- **n** para buscar desordenado

Vamos dizer que a gente tenha 10K elementos

Para **ordenar e buscar**:

```
10K.log(10K)+log(10K) = 44K de eficiência
```

Para apenar buscar **desordenado** seriam apenas:

```
10K = 10k eficiência
```

A busca desordenada é mais rápida do que ordenar e buscar.
O problema de ordenar a lista é que seu custo é muito alto.
Então nunca seria mais eficiente ordenar antes de buscar para **apenas 1 unica busca**.

Se tivesse que fazer mais busca ai o custo desta ordenação inicial sumiria.

Por exemplo para esta busca, se fosse feito 10 vezes teríamos:

```
Ordenado: 44+40 = 88
Desordenado: 10*10 = 100
```

Lembrando que a eficiência O(1) é a mais eficiente, então 88 é melhor que 100.